More storage in vmWare ESXi
we have a HPE ProLiant ML350 G10 on which ESXi 7.0 Sp 1 is installed and which had until yesterday three SSD drives with a capacity of 2TB each. They were arranged in an RAID 5. Yesterday we introduced a fourth drive with the same capacity to the server. We restartet the server and added the new drive to the RAID via "Intelligent Provisioning". Now in the ESXi the storage has not yet changed and I don't know how to procede. When I go to "storage" and chose the existing datastorage I have a button "increase capacity". But no matter which of the options I chose in the following dialog I always get "no devices with free storage" afterwards.
